# Replace the last and first integers of a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this : `var input = "/first_part/5/another_part/3/last_part"`

I want to replace the last occurence of integers (`3` in my string), then the first occurence (`5`).

I tried this: `input .replace(/\d+/, 3);` which replace all occurences. But how to only target the last / first one.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will replace the first and last single digit in the input string with `3`

`input.replace(/^(.*?)\d(.*)\d(.*)$/, "$13$23$3");`

More readable:

```
var replacement = '3';
input.replace(/^(.*?)\d(.*)\d(.*)$/, "$1" + replacement + "$2" + replacement + "$3");
```

or `input.replace(/^(.*?)\d(.*)\d(.*)$/, ["$1", "$2", "$3"].join(replacement));` if that's your thing.

Comment: Thanks @tom, nice answer. But i haven't understood the regex pattern. did you want to use `(.*?)` or this `(.*)` for the first part ?

Comment: Very nice @Tom, I succeeded it using your solution. I have removed the `?` in the regex corresponding to `first_part`. Like the `join` method to, didn't know it before. thanks a lot

Comment: The `.*?` in the first part is to make the selection non-greedy so it stops after it hits the first digit.  If you leave that out and have, for example 3 digits, it will change the second rather than the first.

Comment: You could also change the first and last `.*` to `\D*`, though I'm not sure how much better that makes it...

Comment: A last question please ? what if i want to replace $1 and $2 with different values ??

Comment: In that case, you could just swap out the `$1` or `$2` with the value you want - these refer to the content matched in the corresponding parentheses.

Comment: ok i see, using the first solution and not the one with `join` method. I see, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
var input = "/first_part/5/another_part/3/last_part";

// replace first number
var r = input.replace(/\d+/, '9').replace(/\d+(?=\D*$)/, '7');
//=> /first_part/9/another_part/7/last_part
```

Here `\d+(?=\D*$)` means match 1 or more digits that are followed by all non-digits till end of line.

Comment: What about the first digit?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty rigid approach to your problem, you might want to adapt it to your needs, but it shows one way you can get things done.

```
// input string
var string = "/first_part/5/another_part/3/last_part";

//match all the parts of the string
var m = string.match(/^(\D+)(\d+)+(\D+)(\d+)(.+)/);

// ["/first_part/5/another_part/3/last_part", "/first_part/", "5", "/another_part/", "3", "/last_part"]

// single out your numbers
var n1 = parseInt(m[2], 10);
var n2 = parseInt(m[4], 10);

// do any operations you want on them
n1 *= 2;
n2 *= 2;

// put the string back together
var output = m[1] + n1 + m[3] + n2 + m[5];

// /first_part/10/another_part/6/last_part
```